# Getting Exception While Using Drools in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, drools

I am trying to implement Drools in **.Net**. I am new to **.Net** as well as Drools.I've read the following document for implementation of Drools:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29165/Getting-Started-with-Drools-NET

I've downloaded this project and it was working fine. Here is my code which I have implemented:-

```
requirementBusinessRules = this;
PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Sdixit\Desktop\LatesetVersion\ReadMails\SimpleRulesExt.drl", FileMode.Open);           
builder.AddPackageFromDrl("SimpleRules.drl", stream);   // Exception
Package pkg = builder.GetPackage();
ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.NewRuleBase();
ruleBase.AddPackage(pkg);           
workingMemory = ruleBase.NewWorkingMemory();           
if (_currentRawMail == null)            
{
    _currentRawMail = requirementBusinessRules.workingMemory.assertObject(em); 
}
else
{
    requirementBusinessRules.workingMemory.modifyObject(_currentRawMail, em);
}
requirementBusinessRules.workingMemory.fireAllRules();
EmailProperties mails = (EmailProperties)requirementBusinessRules.workingMemory.getObject(_currentRawMail);
```

But I am getting an Exception `"NullReferenceException unhandled by user code .object reference not set to an instance of an object."` What to do Now?? What am I missing here?? I went through [Drools: NullPointerException when addPackageFromDrl(source) is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849866/drools-nullpointerexception-when-addpackagefromdrlsource-is-called)

I am using Drools 3.0 and Visual Studio 2012 
Thanks

Edit
Below is the Call Stack

```
drools.dotnet.dll!org.drools.dotnet.semantics.DotnetBaseClassFieldExtractor.DotnetBaseClassFieldExtractor(java.lang.Class clazz, string fieldName) Line 61 + 0x13 bytes C#
drools.dotnet.dll!org.drools.dotnet.semantics.DotnetClassFieldExtractorFactory.getClassFieldExtractor(java.lang.Class clazz, string fieldName) Line 50 + 0x1b bytes C#
[External Code] 
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.base.ClassFieldExtractor.init() Line 73 + 0x58 bytes  Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.base.ClassFieldExtractor.ClassFieldExtractor(java.lang.Class clazz, string fieldName) Line 53 Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.base.ClassFieldExtractorCache.getExtractor(java.lang.Class clazz, string fieldName) Line 27 + 0x1d bytes  Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.semantics.java.RuleBuilder.getFieldExtractor(org.drools.lang.descr.PatternDescr descr, java.lang.Class clazz, string fieldName) Line 998 + 0x1b bytes Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.semantics.java.RuleBuilder.build(org.drools.rule.Column column, org.drools.lang.descr.LiteralDescr literalDescr) Line 527 + 0x36 bytes    Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.semantics.java.RuleBuilder.build(org.drools.lang.descr.ColumnDescr columnDescr) Line 431 + 0x36 bytes Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.semantics.java.RuleBuilder.build(org.drools.lang.descr.RuleDescr ruleDescr) Line 303 + 0x3e bytes Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.semantics.java.RuleBuilder.build(org.drools.rule.Package pkg, org.drools.lang.descr.RuleDescr ruleDescr) Line 203 Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addRule(org.drools.lang.descr.RuleDescr ruleDescr) Line 337 + 0x1b bytes  Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(org.drools.lang.descr.PackageDescr packageDescr) Line 204 + 0x4a bytes Unknown
drools-3.0.dll!org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(string fileName, java.io.Reader reader) Line 129    Unknown
drools.dotnet.dll!org.drools.dotnet.compiler.PackageBuilder.AddPackageFromDrl(string fileName, System.IO.Stream drlStream) Line 78 + 0x2b bytes C#
```

> ReadMails.exe!ReadMails.RequirementBusinessRules.Drool(ReadMails.EmailProperties em) Line 37 + 0x13 bytes   C#
>       ReadMails.exe!ReadMails.ReadEmails.ReadMails() Line 92 + 0x10 bytes C#
>       ReadMails.exe!ReadMails.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 14 + 0xa bytes C#
>       [External Code]

Any Suggestions please.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the full stack trace in the exception.

Comment: Drools 3.0 is paleolithic, sort of. Don't expect much support: Drools is into version 6.0 right now.

Comment: Will it support .Net?? Because Once I downloaded it but it contains only .jar files @laune

Comment: @ShyamDixit Drools is purely Java. Why .NET?

Comment: Because I am doing my this component in .Net and I have found that we can use Drools.So if there is any later version of Drools 3.0 then please tell me or send me the link(so i can use it in my .Net project).Or something else what I need to do?? @laune

Comment: @ShyamDixit I think 3.0 is the only version. - As there is no other reply, you might try the Drools user list: rules-users@lists.jboss.org

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate .NET with Drools, you would be best avoiding using a ropy old, unmaintained .NET port of Drools. And I don't know why anyone would want to start a project in the knowledge that they will never be able to upgrade Visual Studio from a version which is already out of date.

It's a little bit more effort, but you can expose Drools functionality as web services using Drools Camel Server (http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.6.0.Final/droolsjbpm-integration-docs/html_single/#ch.server) or by rolling your own web services. You can then just call those web services from your .NET application.

Otherwise, just go with something on the .NET platform. Admittedly there seems to be nothing in the way of solid open source solutions, but Microsoft provide Windows Workflow Foundation for process management, and StreamInsight for CEP. And I'm sure there must be other commercial rules engines out there for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Drools 3.0 is the last version for .Net Application. And There are updated versions for Java Application. As I mentioned in my question that I am working in Visual Studio 2012. So I tried in Visual Studio 2010 It is working. Either we can go for other Rules Engine or we can make it using VS 2010.

Thanks!!